# How can I correct this regular expression to capture all the repeating parameter groups in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, http-headers, preg-match-all

I am trying to parse the HTTP Accept header to extract all the details from it.
I am making the following assumptions:

Each entry must start with and contain at least `type/subtype`, optionally with a `+basetype`
For example `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`
Entries are separated by a comma.
After the initial `type/subtype`, the entry may contain a variable number of parameter `key=value` pairs, separated by a semicolon (whitespace is allowed between semicolons but not between `=` of `key=value` pair)
For example `application/xhtml+xml; q=0.8; test=hello`

I want to get all of this information into an array.

What I currently have is `preg_match_all('/([^,;\/=\s]+)\/([^,;\/=\s+]+)(\+([^,;\/=\s+]+))?(\s?;\s?([^,;=]+)=([^,;=]+))*/', $header, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);` which, to my mind, gives an initial capture group with the type, then one with the subtype, then an optional one with the basetype, then an optional repeating one, separated by `;`, which contains the two `key=value`.

When used with a header string `application/xhtml+xml; q=0.9; level=3 , text/html,application/json;test=hello` this gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/xhtml+xml; q=0.9; level=3 
            [1] => application
            [2] => xhtml
            [3] => +xml
            [4] => xml
            [5] => ; level=3 
            [6] => level
            [7] => 3 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html
            [1] => text
            [2] => html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/json;test=hello 
            [1] => application
            [2] => json
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => ;test=hello 
            [6] => test
            [7] => hello 
        )

)
```

which is fine except that only the last `key=value` is given for the first entry (`application/xhtml+xml; q=0.9; level=3`), the `q=0.9` is missing.

Is there any way I can include all the (variable number of) parameters in each match, while still using just the one regular expression, or do I have to use a separate regular expression / function for the `key=value` pairs?

**EDIT:**

The kind of array result I would like is this (obviously items 0, 3, 5, 8... etc for each content type are unnecessary, but I don't know if they can be excluded):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/xhtml+xml; q=0.9; level=3 
            [1] => application
            [2] => xhtml
            [3] => +xml
            [4] => xml
            [5] => ; q=0.9 
            [6] => q
            [7] => 0.9 
            [8] => ; level=3 
            [9] => level
           [10] => 3 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html
            [1] => text
            [2] => html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/json;test=hello 
            [1] => application
            [2] => json
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => ;test=hello 
            [6] => test
            [7] => hello 
        )

)
```

This allows me to grab the key and value for each parameter without doing any further regexp or string functions.

**EDIT**

I have accepted **Ka**'s answer, which seems to give me all that I need.
Using his pattern `(?:\G\s?,\s?|^)(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?|(?<!^)\G(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))` on the same string (without the set order) gives the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/xhtml+xml
            [1] => ; q=0.9
            [2] => ; level=3
            [3] =>  , text/html
            [4] => ,application/json
            [5] => ;test=hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => application
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => text
            [4] => application
            [5] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => xhtml
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => html
            [4] => json
            [5] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => xml
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => q
            [2] => level
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => test
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 0.9
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => hello
        )

)
```

from which I can compile an associative array using the array of index 1 to determine the boundaries between the individual content types with their parameters.

Many thanks to Ka for his/her help.

**EDIT:**

Changed the expression again - the expression also needs to be able to parse wildcard mimes such as `text/*`.
So the expression now becomes:

```
(?:\G\s?,\s?|^)(\w+|\*)\/(\w+|\*)(?:\+(\w+))?|(?<!^)\G(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little different than your desired output but will safely get all the values without the ones you don´t need:

RegEx: `(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?|(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))` *(with global flag **g**)*
Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/fM1gJ2
*Edit: This is better used on already validated  headers as it´s composed with a regex `or`, you can use this regex `\w+\/\w+(\+\w+)?(\s?;\s?\w+=[\w\.]+)*` to validate.*

OR

Something along the lines:

RegEx: `(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))?`
with the last part `(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))?` repeated as many times you think you´ll have to
Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yI6uS1

### Update:

Validation and capture on the same go using global flag **g**
RegEx: `(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?|(?<!^)\G(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/bR7kU2
**Update** *(content types must always be separated by a comma)*
RegEx: `(?:\G\s?,\s?|^)(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?|(?<!^)\G(?:\s?;\s?(\w+)=([\w\.]+))`
Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nG4oV0

And a shorter repeating end pattern for v2: `(?:\s?;\s?((?4))=((?5)))?` in case you increase the `key=value` character sets, [explained here](http://regex101.com/r/iH0pD8). Or even shorter if you allow some unnecessary data to get saved in the array with this regex:

```
(\w+)\/(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?(\s?;\s?([\w-]+)=([\w!:\$\.-]+))?((?4))?
```

and repeat `((?4))?` as needed, [see it here](http://regex101.com/r/hC2xB1).

Comment: That's looking good, but how would I go about finding the separating point of each content type in the first one? The second one would obviously probably be fine for 99% of cases, but I would prefer to be able to handle an unknown number of parameter. I see you used the special word tag rather than faffing about with non-permitted characters - again that is probably fine for most cases, but I can't actually find any RFC which defines which characters are permitted where (escaping is permitted for params but that really is too complicated).

Comment: I've been trying with your first example, and I'm thinking that if I can include the `,` as a third alternative, then I will know to start on the next content type when iterating over the result array whenever I have the comma match.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've accepted your answer. I'm not quite sure why my PHP gives different results to the site you linked to, but then its implementation is opaque, so I don't know what PHP code they would use.

Comment: Actually, belay that - sorry, but I've just realised that this expression will not match only correctly formatted headers - if we add something like `application/;q=3` this will generate matches, while not actually being a correct content type, so using the `|` is out of the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry I was under the impression you're feeding valid headers to the regex, updated post to include various concerns. About variable names, usually it´s a safer bet to allow a few characters rather than to disallow a lot, they're usually made up of letters, numbers and hyphens. Still thinking about including a comma as a 3rd alternative? How?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have said that I want invalid header parts to fail - we don't control what clients send as headers. The updated version (first variant) looks good to me. I still don't get the same output in PHP as on the site, but that is ok because it allows me to see the boundaries. There is still one problem however - content types must always be separated by a comma, whereas this allows separation by a space. No need to use comma as 3rd alternative for me, since PHP shows all matches, from which I can determine the boundary. Thanks a lot for your help with this.

Comment: Pretty much perfect! I removed the newlines from the example (a newline character would automatically make the header invalid anyway). It ignores everything from the first time that a comma is skipped, but that is not a bad thing anyway. Thank you for all the time you have spent on this.

Comment: I've modified your expression again - I forgot that valid Accept headers can include wildcard paths such as `text/*`, so I've modified it to take this into account.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you use php's parse functions instead of trying to write your own.

See this for details: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php

and more particularly for your situation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php

Comment: Thanks for that info - I wasn't aware of those functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-content-type.php would seem best for me. However, I won't accept the answer because is does not answer the question of how to capture the params in a regular expression, and I cannot use the native PHP function because it does not allow server priorities to be taken into account (only matches the highest client q), and I want control over the negotiation.